# Pyyhon encryption code - Help me understand the logic of a Python code which has some encryption logic in it

Tags: python

I have a python code. I am pretty new to python. could some one please explain what this piece of code dose.

From what I can understand this piece of code is trying to decry-pt the ID's.
We pass in the ID's with a CSV file. I am unable to understand the logic line by line. Specially the hashfn.hexdigest and insert lines

```
import csv
import hashlib
seed_val = b'197504'
outfile = open('ID_nos_hashed.csv','a')
with open('ID_nos_input.csv', 'rb') as infile:
  for inline in infile.readlines():
    linearray = inline.split(',')
    first_item = linearray[0]
    hashfn = hashlib.sha1()
    hashfn.update(first_item)
    hashfn.update(seed_val)
    lc_num_hash = hashfn.hexdigest()
    uc_num_hash = lc_num_hash.upper()
    insert_list = []
    insert_list.append(first_item)
    insert_list.append(uc_num_hash)
    insert_string = ','.join(insert_list)+'\n'
    outfile.write(insert_string)
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This code creates a hash table from a CSV (comma separated value)
file. It operates as follows.

- It opens the output file `ID_nos_hashed.csv`
- It opens the date source `ID_nos_input.csv`. It is most likely a list
  of CSVs where each line of this file is a data record.
- The script extracts the first entry (column) of each data
  record and assigns it to `first_item`.
- The script computes the hash value

  hashfn= SHA-1(first_item || seed_val)

  where `'||'` denotes the (string) concatenation operator.
- The script converts the 160-bit hash value `hashfn` to an hex string
  uc_num_hash where each digit is either a numeral or an upper case letters. Thus, the hex alphabet is 0123456789ABCDEF.
- The hex string (uc_num_hash) of the hash value is then assigned to uc_num_hash.
- The scripts appends the line first_item,uc_num_hash to the output file.

Note that `hashfn` can contain non printable characters. It is convert
into an hex string to make it human readable.

**Further information:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

PS.: The data is neither encrypted nor decrypted. Both operations require a key. This script just generates a (inverted index) hash table from a set of data to minimize the access time for accessing an individual entry.